# Write smart contract using Solidity over Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, solidity

I'm trying to write a basic smart contract using solidity over Intellij.
I've installed Intellij. I've installed the [intellij-solidity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9475-intellij-solidity) plugin and started Intellij --> Create new Project.
I expect to see an option that relates to solidity but can't see such.

How do I start using Solidity over Intellij?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Intellij-Solidity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9475-intellij-solidity) plugin adds Solidity language support. It means syntax highlighting, autocomplete and similar things.

It will not appear in the list of Project types you can create. Just start with an "Empty Project" and create your sol files there manually.

Comment: Just to add to this. It is possible to create .sol files (with the ethereum logo as a file icon) just not entire projects.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij-Solidity
gives only highlight syntax
and no autocomplete